# Transparent AppBarLayout with CardView within it

Tags: android, android-design-library

The goal is to implement replacement for ToolBar which looks more like 'SearchView', for example: search in Google Play application. This view should also react accordingly (slide away) when RecyclerView in ViewPager is scrolled down, and slide in when user scrolls list up.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Basically, implementation of the view itself is not complex at all.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <!-- Other boring implementation details -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- TabLayout which is used as indicator for ViewPager -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Ok, so result looks like this before scrolling down (since `windowBackground` is set to be white, `AppBarLayout` seems to be transparent now): 
[image]

but after scrolling...
[image]

instead of transparent background, AppBarLayout remained white. So instead of desired transparent background like in first screenshot, I got white for unknown reason.

Does anyone faced this issue before? Is there any clean solution to this problem?

P.S. I found out interesting behavior: if I remove `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from `ViewPager`, `AppBarLayout` remains transparent as it should be even after scrolling. It means problem is located somewhere in ScrollViewBehavior but I did not manage to find it out.

Answer (score 1):

The `AppBarLayout` isn't white. What you are seeing is the window background of your Activity.

What `layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` does is affect the measurement and layout of the view depending on a sibling `AppBarLayout`. Part of that effect is to offset the vertical position of the view so that it is always below the `AppBarLayout`. That is why you are seeing the window background beneath; there is no View occupying that space, and thus nothing is being drawn there besides the window.

It seems like you may not want to use `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` and instead just allow them to overlap always (which is what you noticed before when you removed that behavior). This presents the problem of how to not cover content when the `RecyclerView` is scrolled to its top and you also have the `AppBarLayout` scrolled onto the screen. A quick solution is to add the following attributes to the `RecyclerView`:

```
<!-- Padding derived from the size and margins of the CardView -->
android:paddingTop="64dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already tried this approach and it works but not completely. ViewPager and RecyclerView without scrolling behavior set to it, does not react to scroll immediately: I suppose AppBarLayout is stealing scrolling event and it returns it back to RecyclerView only after sliding out of the screen, which feels very unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

[@Karakuri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384635/6762137) has a decent approach, but a smoother scrolling experience can be achieved through dynamically setting the listview's padding using the AppBarLayout's **addOnOffsetChangedListener**

```
appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener((barLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
   int offset = barLayout.getMeasuredHeight() + verticalOffset;
   mListView.setPaddingRelative(0, offset, 0, 0);
});
```